# Getting error while Executing Package

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

Table Structure:

```
Name       Null Type         
---------- ---- ------------ 
DPT_NO          NUMBER       
SALARY          NUMBER(10)   
PERIOD          VARCHAR2(10) 
START_DATE      DATE         
END_DATE        DATE
```

Package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body salary_sal AS
   PROCEDURE find_sal(c_dpt_no salary.dpt_no%TYPE) IS
   c_sal salary.salary%TYPE;
   BEGIN
      SELECT salary INTO c_sal
      FROM salary
      WHERE c_dpt_no= 108;
      dbms_output.put_line('Salary: '|| c_sal);
   END find_sal;
END salary_sal;
```

while executing above I'm getting following error

```
Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Error(1,14): PLS-00201: identifier 'SALARY_SAL' must be declared
Error(1,14): PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'SALARY_SAL' without its specification.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the declaration of the package. The idea is to separate the declaration of the package ("the header", if you will), so other packages/procedures/functions can compile against it from the body (the implementation).

In your case, you'd need something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package salary_sal AS
   PROCEDURE find_sal(c_dpt_no salary.dpt_no%TYPE);
END salary_sal;
```

Now, once the package is declared, you can create its body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body salary_sal AS
   PROCEDURE find_sal(c_dpt_no salary.dpt_no%TYPE) IS
   c_sal salary.salary%TYPE;
   BEGIN
      SELECT salary INTO c_sal
      FROM salary
      WHERE c_dpt_no= 108;
      dbms_output.put_line('Salary: '|| c_sal);
   END find_sal;
END salary_sal;
```

Comment: these two package will be execute separately?

Comment: These are two different statements. This way you can create your package ("header") once and alter the body ("implementation") many times without have to break/re-compile other packages depending on it.

Comment: why we declare another package here?

Comment: This is not another package - it the package and its body. See [Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm#433) for more details.

Comment: how to execute this package?

Answer (score 0):

The package needs a specification (i.e. a separate interface definition) as the error message says. You would have to add something like before the definition of the package body (i.e. its implementation):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package salary_sal AS
   PROCEDURE find_sal(c_dpt_no salary.dpt_no%TYPE);
END salary_sal;
/
```

Comment: where to add your answer,i mean in package or body section ?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with "package section." Add that before your `CREATE OR REPLACE package body salary_sal ...` in your code. It is separate from the body but required by it.

Comment: how to execute package?

Comment: Packages do not get executed. They are containers for procedures, functions, types etc. It is kind of a code "module" in PL/SQL and has separate _interface_ and _implementation_ allowing other modules or code using the package while the implementation can vary (and have "private" procedures for example not mentioned in the package specification.) One example is the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package you are using. Its implementation may change between versions of Oracle but you do not need to care about that, you just rely on the specification (i.e. interface) of that module.

Comment: well explanation.we can using these package by another implementation  process like  select and etc,.Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to create a package specifications and then only you can create a package body.

You need to execute the package i.e you execute the stored procedures,functions etc in the package.